# R output tsv without scientific notation

Tags: r, format

I have this variable:

```
> output
[[1]]
[1] 1.394082e+19 3.481687e+18 1.829848e+19 1.414608e+19 1.694183e+19 1.394082e+19

[[2]]
[1] 1.569580e+19 1.569580e+19 1.204701e+19 1.600159e+19 6.915915e+18 4.672586e+18 1.095256e+19 1.395906e+19 2.199774e+18

[[3]]
[1] 1.602384e+19 2.610937e+18 1.750534e+19 3.749841e+17 1.602384e+19 1.921356e+18 1.490877e+19 1.858905e+17 9.592238e+18

[[4]]
[1] 1.488400e+19 8.239013e+18 1.397958e+19 1.488400e+19 5.659786e+17 1.235961e+18 1.802728e+19

[[5]]
[1] 1.038415e+19 5.060804e+18 3.892644e+18 1.038415e+19
```

I want to print to a tsv file without scientific notation. Something like

```
1.56958e+19     1.56958e+19     1.204701e+19    1.600159e+19    6.915915e+18
4.672586e+18    1.095256e+19    1.395906e+19    2.199774e+18
1.602384e+19    2.610937e+18    1.750534e+19    3.749841e+17    1.602384e+19
1.921356e+18    1.490877e+19    1.858905e+17    9.592238e+18
1.4884e+19      8.239013e+18    1.397958e+19    1.4884e+19      5.659786e+17
```

but without scientific notation. If I try,

```
x <- c(1:length(output)))
for ( val in x ) {
  write(format(output[[val]],scientific = FALSE),file="test2.txt", append=TRUE,sep="\t")
}
```

I get new lines for every number:

```
13940817034235316224
 3481686930273376256
18298477684861163520
14146076755830216704
16941832990896044032
13940817034235316224
15695800775901642752
15695800775901642752
```

Ive tried a few variations and having little experience with R leads me to believe I'm missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the `ncolumns` parameter explicitly. According to `?write`, the default for `ncolumns` is:

> ncolumns = if(is.character(x)) 1 else 5

Since `format` converts the numeric vector to a character vector, you always have one column per line; Programmatically you can set the `ncolumns` equal to the length of vector for each sublist:

```
for(vec in output) {
    write(format(vec, scientific=FALSE), file="test2.txt", append=TRUE, sep="\t", ncolumns=length(vec))
}
```